# Fade in, fade out div with images and text (with jquery)

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to click on a photographer's photo on the portfolioMain page; this will then take them to information about the photographer. When they're done there, they can then click "back," which will then take them back to the portfolioMain.

It use to work perfectly fine but I messed up somewhere in the script or html. So now when I click back, the photographer's information still shows and does not fadeout. Can anyone see what I could I have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Your edit makes this question and its answers completely useless to anybody else and completely destroys its context. If you didn't want the code "public", you shouldn't have posted it on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your JavaScript code in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it is wrapped. I just didn't paste it on here.. there's other codes in this script file

Comment: @Jacqueline Nguyen ：well then, there must be some issues in somewhere else, at least this snippet works well

Comment: thanks for trying. It's really frustrating... I would like to move on to another part of the project, but I would eventually like for this to work =/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be because you have not initialised the document state correctly at the beginning. Otherwise, your code seems to work fine (at least with jQuery 1.6.4).

Here is the working jsFiddle, with the "quick hack" of calling the back link functionality at the start of `$(document).ready()` to set the state correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/RFra9/1/

Obviously, the way it 'flashes' is not ideal, so you will want to ensure the HTML gets rendered initially with the right elements hidden (set their `style` attribute to `display: none;`), and then remove the `$(document).ready()` call to `backToMain()`.

Does that make sense? Let me know if not.

Oh, and while you are there - technically, `<br>` should be `<br />`, and all `<img>` tags should be self-closing as well (`<img ... />`) - the one for Vanessa isn't.

**EDIT:** Okay, after having looked at the page, aside from all the broken image paths (most due to the missing `.` in the filename), I think the problem with the `.portfolioDetail:visible` div not fading out correctly is due to your use of floats. Now, I'm no float expert, but I did get the desired behaviour by adding `<div style="clear: both;">` to the end of each portfolioDetail div, e.g:

```
<div id="william" class="portfolioDetail" style="display: none; ">
<div class="quadColumn">
<img src="img/galleryicon2jpg">
</div>
<div class="quadColumn endColumn"> 
<p>I really enjoyed William's ability to "make scenes come alive". And in our work together, that's exactly what he captured. I thoroughly enjoyed working with William</p> 
<p><a href="http://www.williamchik.com" target="_blank">www.williamchik.com</a></p>
<br>
<p><a href="#" class="back">Back</a></p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div> /* here */
</div>
```

I'm not sure which CSS framework you are using, as there might be a way to make sure the float is cleared with a special class or something, but adding the div manually (as well as re-binding the `$(',back')` functionality, I'm not sure why that didn't work with my changes) did fix it for me.

Does that help at all? Try fixing the image paths and add the clearing div on the test site you linked to, and I'll have a look if it still doesn't work.

Comment: The website is: http://www.vanessaphil.com/sample.html and when you go to Gallery, you'll see what happens when you click the picture then click back...

Comment: sorry, I don't understand where to put "backToMain()"

Comment: `backToMain()` isn't actually necessary, you have got all the styles in place on the actual site. Follow my updated answer instead. Btw, nice looking site, and the girl is quite the looker. :-)

Comment: Also, check out my jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7g3an/) that shows a more succinct way of doing that same code. Note how I used the `rel` attribute on the `<a>` tags to specify the ID of the div to fade to. It also makes it easily extendible without having to modify your javascript.

Comment: The clear div did the magic! Thanks so much for your help! Yes, she is very gorgeous. =)

Comment: Yes, that way looks much more clean. Thanks again Greg!

Comment: No probs, glad to help. I love your work, too. It will be a great looking site once it is done.